# SPI communications with an IMU

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, imu

I am pairing an Arduino UNO with a Yost Labs 3-Space Sensor Nano, the user manual for said sensor can be found here: [1](https://yostlabs.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/pdf/3-Space-Sensor-Users-Manual-Nano.pdf).

This is my code, pretty straight forward (although this is my first time working with SPI). I am 100% sure the wiring is correct.

I believe that as per the user manual, this should successfully return 3 floats in 4 bytes each, corresponding to the filtered euler angles of pitch, yaw, and roll. However, all I am reading is bytes full of 0xFF which I believe corresponds to null / no command.

Are there any visible errors in my code?

```
#include <SPI.h>

SPISettings settings(6000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0 ); //variable to hold SPI settings
//Set Slave Select, MOSI, MISO, CLK 
const int CSN = 10;
const int SI = 11;
const int SO = 12;
const int CLK = 13;

// Needed to convert the bytes from SPI to float
union u_types {
   byte b[4];
   float fval;
} data[3];  // Create 3 unions, one for each euler angle

void setup() {
 //Set Pin Modes
 pinMode(CSN, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(SI, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(SO, INPUT);
 pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
 //Set Slave Select High to Start i.e disable chip
 digitalWrite(CSN, HIGH);
 //Initialize SPI
 SPI.begin();
 //pour a bowl of serial
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

//function to transfer commands through SPI
byte transferByte(byte byteToWrite) {

 byte Result = 0x00;
 digitalWrite(CSN,LOW);
 delay(1);
 Result = SPI.transfer(byteToWrite);
 delay(1);
 digitalWrite(CSN,HIGH);
 return Result; 
}

//function to swap endian
void endianSwap(byte temp[4]) {
 byte myTemp = temp[0];
 temp[0] = temp[3];
 temp[3] = myTemp;
 myTemp = temp[1];
 temp[1] = temp[2];
 temp[2] = myTemp;
}

void loop() {
 SPI.beginTransaction(settings);

 // Clear the internal data buffer on the IMU
 byte result = transferByte(0x01);
     Serial.print("Cleared internal buffer. Result: "),Serial.println(result);

 // Send start of packet:
 result = transferByte(0xF6);
      Serial.print("Send start of packet. Result: "),Serial.println(result);
 
 // Send command (tared euler angles)
 result = transferByte(0x01);
      Serial.print("Send commmand 0x01. Result: "),Serial.println(result);
 
 // Get status of device:
 result = transferByte(0xFF);
      Serial.print("Status of device. Result: "),Serial.println(result);

 while (result != 0x01) {  // Repeat until device is Ready
   delay(1);
   result = transferByte(0xFF);
   Serial.print("Status of device. Result: "),Serial.println(result);
 }
 
 // Get the 12 bytes of return data from the device:
 for (int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
   for (int jj=0; jj<4; jj++) {
     data[ii].b[jj] =  transferByte(0xFF);
     delay(1);
   }
 }  

 SPI.endTransaction();

 for( int mm=0; mm<3; mm++) {
   endianSwap(data[mm].b);
 }
 
 
 Serial.print("fval 1:"), Serial.println(data[0].fval);
 Serial.print("fval 2:"), Serial.println(data[1].fval);
 Serial.print("fval 3:"), Serial.println(data[2].fval);

 delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: not the problem, but SPI.begin() configures the SPI pins so your list of pin numbers and pinmode settings are unnecessary for MOSI, MISO and CLK

Comment: the sensor is not 5V tolerant. how did you wire it?

Comment: @hcheung not sure where am I using the Arduino board as a slave here?

Comment: @Juraj SPI.beingTransaction(settings) uses my pin numbers and settings, downstream from SPI.begin(), correct?

Comment: @Juraj Wiring graphic: https://i.imgur.com/ShAVLqc.jpg

Comment: hardware SPI pins on Uno are not selectable. I don't see level conversion in the picture? is the device SPI master?

Comment: If I read the section 4.4.1 of the datasheet correctly, you send a write command `0xE9` follow by a TSS command to tell the device what you want to retrieve, and if the return value is either `0x00` or `0x06`, you send a `0x69` to read the data. I don't see your code is doing that. In fact, I have hard time to find where you get those commands that you used from the data sheet.